# A question on the terminal in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I downloaded Petsc directory from here:
https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/download/index.html

Now I want to follow up on the following instructions:
https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html

The quick instructions:

```
./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-fblaslapack --download-mpich
make all test
```

Now the file that I downloaded is in the downloads directory, I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to prompt the terminal; how to proceed with the terminal and to implement the above instructions?

Comment: Use \`  before and after text \` to format commands instead of " "

Comment: @kalenpw you might explain what those commands are, and how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Nautilus file manager (the `Files` icon in the Unity launcher) to open the folder with the source code. Right-click the mouse pointer anywhere in that window and select `Open in Terminal`.

**Update**: If you don't have "Open in Terminal" installed, you'll have to change to the source code folder manually. If (for example) a folder called `Petsc` is in your Downloads folder... then open a fresh terminal window and type `cd ~/Downloads/Petsc` (this is case sensitve), then proceed with the installation instructions.

Then proceed with the installation. Understand that the quick instructions you listed are actually two separate commands...

```
./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-fblaslapack --download-mpich
```

and

```
make all test
```

Comment: Note: It may be necessary to install the `build-essential` package before being able to compile software. To do so, just run the command `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: How to install Nautilus file manager? I don't find the instructions and downloads page in this webpage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nautilus ?

Comment: Nautilus file manager is already a part of your Ubuntu installation. It's the `Files` icon in the Unity launcher.

Comment: I don't have this option:"Open in Terminal"; I did exactly what you said, I opened the unity and press right click somewhere in the window, the options are: "New Folder - New Document - Paste - Properties". I also downloaded the build essential through the terminal with what @NickWeinberg suggested.

Comment: Ah, I forget that not everybody has "Open in Terminal" installed. Give me a minutes to edit my answer...

Comment: It seems I need to upgrade my UBUNTU which is now on its way so to speak.

Comment: OK, now that I updated ubuntu I have the opened Downloads files directory, but the option of open terminal is only possible when I don't touch Right click on the the file petsc-3.7.4.tar.gz but just press it somewhere which is not the files in this directory. I tried writing the code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: First you have to uncompress petsc-3.7.4.tar.gz. Right-click on it and select `extract here`. It'll probably create a folder called *something* like petsc-3.7.4. Then in terminal, type `cd ~/Downloads/petsc-3.7.4`. Then you can do the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what alt-shift-t does, but you can do the following to invoke your installation:

Start the Terminal (from the dash, for example). When you start the Terminal, you will usually find yourself in your home directory. You can list all files and folders with the ls command (use ls -a to see hidden files and folders, starting with a . )

```
ls
```

Now, you can change to your Downloads folder, using the cd (change directory) command:

```
cd Downloads
ls
```

The last ls should give you a list of the contents of the Downloads directory. Find out in which folder you put the PETSc, and then change into it using cd. From there, you can invoke the command you gave in your question.